# Converting Struct to JSON where a field is another Struct

Tags: json, go, bson

I have two structs struct:

```
type A struct {
    Zip string `json:"zip"`
}

type B struct {
    Foo string `bson:"foo"`
    Bar A      `json:"bar"`
}
```

When I try to `json.Marshal` the `B` type, the `Bar` field does not get converted correctly. The fields are OK, but the values are always empty. The output looks like this:

`{"foo": "some-string-value", "bar": {"zip": ""}}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you populating the **Zip** field ? and how ?

Comment: All fields are populated `Bar` is populated with an instance of `A`. And that instance has `Zip` populated.

Comment: The Zip field of A is not populated. Focus on finding out why.

Comment: It is populated. When I have an instance of `B`, I simply do B.Bar = a, `a` being an instance of `A` previously populated correctly.

Comment: What do you get if you `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", b)`?

Comment: The values correctly populated. It's when I try to save the whole thing to a JSON file that the empty values appear in the struct field.

Answer (score 4):

Your Zip field in A is not populated.

```
type A struct {
    Zip string `json:"zip"`
}

type B struct {
    Foo string `bson:"foo"`
    Bar A      `json:"bar"`
} 
func main() {
    one := A{"35000"}
    two := B{"Foo", one}
    json, _ := json.Marshal(two)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", json)
}
```

Output is (https://play.golang.org/p/kyG1YabpSe):

```
{"Foo":"Foo","bar":{"zip":"35000"}}
```

Even with a map

```
type A struct {
   Zip string `json:"zip"`
}
type B struct {
   Foo string `bson:"foo"`
   Bar A      `json:"bar"`
}
func main() {
   m := make(map[string]B)

   for x := 0; x < 10; x++ {
      m[strconv.Itoa(x)] = B{"Hello", A{"35000"}}
   }

   json, _ := json.Marshal(m)
   fmt.Printf("%s\n", json)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/qCsmAGzo4H

Output is good, i don't understand where you are wrong.

Comment: I have a map of `B` items, and when I try to `json.Marshal(myMap)`, the `Bar` field is populated with empty string values.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro Can you update your question with the exact code the problem is observed in ? There is no mention of `myMap` or map of `B` items in the question.